# Rank of an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I learned that a rank of an abelian group is defined by a cardinality of  maximal linearly independent sets. But how we can say that this is well-defined? I mean, I want to show that if $M$ and $N$ are maximal linearly independent sets, then $M$ and $N$ have same cardinality. I already proved in the case of finite cardinality, but I can't prove in the case of infinite.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you explain in more details why you think it is not well-defined or what you have tried to show this. Maybe you could include the finite cardinality case, that might help people to understand better.

Comment: Have you ever heard the localization of an abelian group?

Comment: @Censi I have never heard about it, but I know about localization of a module. Is it same?

Comment: @Kim It's simply a particular case of localization of a module, since an abelian group is just a $\mathbb Z$-module. If you've known this notion, I suggest you to prove that a subset of $M$ is $\mathbb Z$-linear independent iff its image in $S^{-1}M$ is  $\mathbb Q$-linear independent ($S$ denotes the set of all nonzero integers, a multilicative subset of $\mathbb Z$).